# SSRS SQL Server 2008 R2: User domains changed; server domain not changed. Users can't login

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I am not the best at the actual inner workings of SQL Server 2008 R2, and we don't really have anyone here who is, so I turn to you, the lovely community of stackoverflow :)

We are moving users to a new domain (there is a two-way trust, and the old domain will be active for quite some time). The users are all being moved in the next few days. We are not moving every machine to the new domain, however. One of the machines we are not moving is the SQL Server. I do not know how to set up users so they can access SSRS via a web browser once they've been moved. Users can still access reports if they login to windows w/the old domain.

Of course, I've opened the report server in the browser, gone into "Site Settings" and added users to roles as 'NewDomain\UserName', but that doesn't work. I'm guessing there's another piece I have to do to say "Hey, look, SQL, there's another domain that is totally cool that you need to recognize!"

I have full access to Management Studio and I am can log into the box itself. I am not involved in the domain change, and know very little about managing Windows and the like, but if that stuff is needed to resolve this, I can get the network group to make the changes.

Thanks.

Comment: When you use mixed mode or windows authentication. It would be ideal to have user domain and server domain same.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. All I had to once I was in the browser was go to "Home" and then "Folder Settings" and add the "newdomain\domain users" user. Am I the only one who always figures things out right after they ask for help?